# How to explain why a parabola opens up or down

Tags: education

I am being ask to explain in two ways why is it that $y=ax^2+bx+c$ parabola opens up if $a$ is positive and why is it that $y=ax^2+bx+c$ opens down when $a$ is negative. One of the explanations has to be understood by beginning algebra student.
I am unsure how I would explain it

Comment: You could consider what happens as $|x|$ becomes very large on either side of the axis, or also alternately complete the square and see the sign.

Comment: Plot $y=x^2$. Explain how $y=ax^2+bx+c$ is related, if $a\gt 0$ (scale, shift). See what reversing signs does.

Answer (score 6):

If $x$ is big and positive, and $a$ is positive, then $ax^2$ will be very big and positive, overwhelming any effect from $bx+c$.

If $x$ is big and negative, and $a$ is positive, then $ax^2$ will again be very big and positive.

So if $a$ is positive, the parabola opens upwards.

If $a$ is negative then if $x$ is big (positive or negative) the opposite occurs, and $ax^2$ will be very big and negative with the parabola opening downwards.

Comment: I think this is the proper beginning algebra approach.  It is a useful precursor to many ideas of limits at $\pm \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that the parabola has a unique minima or maxima depending on whether $a$ is positive or negative respectively using the second derivative idea. This is the calculus way. In the algebraic way, I guess plotting is one option.

Comment: for telling a beginning algebra student. I first started by explaining that if a>o, y=ax^2, y will always be positive and it will open up because the first and second quadrant are where the y is always positive. But I dont know how to transition that into y=ax^2+bx+c

Answer (score 0):

One more method:

You know the parabola $y = ax^2 + bx+c$ can be written as:
$$y - y_0 = a(x-x_0)^2$$
Since this is just the parabola "shifted" to the axis. Now since $(x-x_0)^2$ is always positive, what determines what the parabola looks like is only $a$.

Answer (score 0):

So I am gonna try to prove from "slope" perspective. I hope it's clear that if our parabola opens upward then slope is positive else negative for say large positive x values.

Consider $ y = ax^2 + bx + c $ with 2 points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. Also we will safely assume $x_2 > x_1 > 0$ i.e. points are on the right side of Y-axis.

Now, slope = $ \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2-x_1} $ = $a(x_1+x_2)+b$.

It must be clear that:

1. $b>0$, then it's pretty straightforward that slope will be positive if $a>0$ and hence parabola opens upward else $a<0$ would imply slope negative and parabola opens downward.
2. $b<0$, If $a<0$ that implies slope negative and parabola opens downward but if $a>0$ we will get $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $a(x_1+x_2) > b$ and hence slope positive implying parabola opening upward.

---

This might convince beginning algebra student else the answer given by Gautam Shenoy about using second-derivative is more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

My usual approach when teaching this topic is a "transformational" approach.  We first understand basic transformations:  if we know what the graph of $f(x)$ looks like, then

- the graph of $f(x-h)$ is the same graph, but translated to the left by $h$ units;
- the graph of $f(x) + k$ is the same graph, but translated up by $k$ units;
- for positive $A$, the graph of $A f(x)$ is the same graph, but scaled vertically by a factor of $A$; and
- the graph of $-f(x)$ is the same graph, reflected vertically across the $x$-axis.

We also discuss horizontal scaling and reflection, but those are not relevant here.  These kinds of transformations are the bread-and-butter of a beginning algebra curriculum, so I would think that they should be pretty accessible at that level.

Next, think about the ur-parabola, $p(x) = x^2$.  The graph of this function is a U-shaped beast which opens up.  Even better, it is possible to show that the graph of *every* quadratic polynomial is a transformed version of the ur-parabola.  That is:

> **Proposition:**  If $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a\ne 0$ (that is, if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are any real numbers with $a$ nonzero), then there are real numbers $A$, $h$, and $k$ such that
>   $$ ax^2 + bx + c = A(x-h)^2 + k. $$

*Proof:*  We will show that such real numbers exist by explicitly solving for them.  Observe that
$$ \color{red}{a}x^2 + \color{purple}{b}x + \color{blue}{c}
= A(x-h)^2 + k
= \color{red}{A}x^2 + \color{purple}{(-2Ah)}x + \color{blue}{(Ah^2 + k)} $$
if and only if the coefficients on the left and right agree.  That is
$$\begin{cases}
\color{red}{a = A} \\
\color{purple}{b = -2Ah} \\
\color{blue}{c = Ah^2 + k} \\
\end{cases}$$
Solving for $A$, $h$, and $k$, we obtain
$$
A = a,
\qquad h = -\frac{b}{2a},
\qquad\text{and}\
\qquad k = c - \frac{b^2}{4a}.
$$
As long as $a \ne 0$ (which was assumed at the beginning), then $A$, $h$, and $k$ can be explicitly found, which gives the desired result.$\tag*{$\square$}$

**Remark:** As a minor aside, notice that we have just derived the "completing the square" formula, and are very close to a complete derivation of the quadratic formula.  Thus this form of the parabola has other uses (including several that I haven't listed).

We have just shown that *every* parabola can be written in the form
$$ ax^2 + bx + c = a\left(x - h \right)^2 + +k. $$
In particular, keeping our transformations in mind, we can graph any parabola by translating the ur-parabola to the right $h$ units, scaling it by a factor of $a$, **possibly reflecting it vertically if $a < 0$**, and translating it up $k$ units (where $h$ and $k$ are constants that we can write down explicitly in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$).  Note in bold that if $a < 0$, then there is a vertical reflection.  This finally leads to the desired explanation:

**Conclusion:** Suppose that we want to know if the graph $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ opens up or down.  To answer this question, we can write the original parabola in terms of transformations, i.e. write
$$ ax^2 + bx + c = a(x-h)^2 + k, $$
and observe that *only* transformation that can change the direction in which the parabola opens is the possible vertical reflection that occurs if $a < 0$.  Therefore if $a > 0$ then the parabola retains its original orientation and opens up, and if $a < 0$ then the parabola is reflected vertically and opens down.